# Amazon api gateway static url

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

Amazon api gateway invoke url for lambda function is changing whenever the cloud formation stack is updated and restarted. How to make this Amzaon api gateway url static through cloud formation script?

Comment: Please post an example CloudFormation template.

Comment: Are you changing the "stage" name every time you run the cloudformation script?